# Angular Firebase Storage and Functions services emulators are not initialized

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-tools

I have successfully implemented Firestore, Auth, Functions and Storage services and now try to activate firebase emulator on my local.

When I debug the project; provideAuth and provideFirestore sections are initialized (getting called) successfully however provideStorage and provideFunctions functions are not getting called.

I assume due to that issue, When I try to upload a file into storage, it is being sent to the production, not to localhost and same applies to functions as well.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  DashboardComponent,
  SignInComponent,
  SignUpComponent,
  ForgotPasswordComponent,
  VerifyEmailComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  AppRoutingModule,    
  provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
  provideFunctions(() => {
    const funcs = getFunctions();
      connectFunctionsEmulator(funcs, "127.0.0.1", 5001);
    return funcs;
  }),
  provideStorage(() => {
    const storage = getStorage();
      connectStorageEmulator(storage, "127.0.0.1", 9199);
    return storage;
  }),
  provideAuth(() => {
    const auth = getAuth();
      connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099", { disableWarnings: true });
    return auth;
  }),
  provideFirestore(() => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
      connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", 8080);
    return firestore;
  }),
  provideRemoteConfig(() => getRemoteConfig()),
],
providers: [AuthService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And that's the environment for development;

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    projectId: 'crProject',
    appId: '1:xxx106x68xxx:web:xxxb3x7d47xxx7dd9c1xxx',
    databaseURL: 'https://crProject-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app',
    storageBucket: 'crProject.appspot.com',
    locationId: 'europe-west',
    apiKey: 'xxzaxxDtCYbgxxxKFxxxxuyLtxxxB3FGxxxqJm8',
    authDomain: 'crProject.firebaseapp.com',
    messagingSenderId: '5xx1xx9xx791',
    measurementId: 'G-xxxZBxHxxx',
  }
};
```

And this is npm list;

```
├── @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.1.0       
├── @angular/animations@16.1.1
├── @angular/cli@16.1.0
├── @angular/common@16.1.1
├── @angular/compiler-cli@16.1.1
├── @angular/compiler@16.1.1
├── @angular/core@16.1.1
├── @angular/fire@7.6.1
├── @angular/forms@16.1.1
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@16.1.1
├── @angular/platform-browser@16.1.1
├── @angular/router@16.1.1
├── @types/jasmine@4.3.4
├── bootstrap@5.3.0
├── firebase-tools@12.4.0
├── firebase@9.22.2
├── jasmine-core@4.6.0
├── karma-chrome-launcher@3.2.0
├── karma-coverage@2.2.0
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@2.1.0
├── karma-jasmine@5.1.0
├── karma@6.4.2
├── ngx-spinner@16.0.2
├── rxjs@7.8.1
├── tslib@2.5.3
├── typescript@5.1.3
└── zone.js@0.13.1
```

Comment: One tip you can use when debugging - when using the emulators a demo project ID will remove any doubt that you may be calling production: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#choose_a_firebase_project

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I have never injected (called) Functions and Storage services appropriately (or the way they were supposed to be injected)

provideFunctions and provideStorage were invoked right after I inject Functions and Storage objects as follows (not via getFunctions and getStorage functions);

From this;

```
import { httpsCallable, getFunctions } from "@angular/fire/functions";

@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root',
})
export class SampleService {
constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public httpClient: HttpClient){
}

public async createImage(imgUrl: string): Promise<ImageResponse> {
    const functions = getFunctions();
    var createEditImage = httpsCallable(functions, "createEditImage");
    return createEditImage({imgUrl: imgUrl})
    .then((result) => {
      const resp = result.data as ImageResponse;
      return resp;
    });
  }
}
```

To This;

```
import { httpsCallable, Functions } from "@angular/fire/functions";

@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root',
})
export class DalleService {
  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public httpClient: HttpClient,
    private functions: Functions){
  }

public async createImage(imgUrl: string): Promise<ImageResponse> {
    var createEditImage = httpsCallable(this.functions, "createEditImage");
    return createEditImage({imgUrl: imgUrl})
    .then((result) => {
      const resp = result.data as ImageResponse;
      return resp;
    });
  }
}
```